# How to create unified, virtualized, triple boot system (Windows, Mac, Linux)

Tags: linux, windows, mac, virtual-machine, multi-boot

I have a new desktop and I don't want to compromise by not using Linux, Mac OS X and Windows--often simultaneously.

My ideal experience would be to be able to virtualize two OS's in the other OS and use any OS for the host OS; e.g., Mac and Linux in VM's on Windows, Windows and Mac in VM's in Linux.

Also I should be able to access any relevant files from any OS (shared partitions)

Assuming hardware is not an issue. What is a way to achieve this or something that approximates thes?

Answer (score 2):

Well that setup requires to have a triple boot and a partition available to all hosts to store 3 virtualized operating systems. That puts you to 6 operating systems total, and possibly a seventh one to be a file server. Think this trough, not the best idea unless you are building a lab.

Another problem might be your HDD crashing. Everything gone, poof! Even restoring backups for an abomination like that is a painful procedure, not to mention any kind of data recovery.

You are going to have filesystem problems too because OSX cant write to NTFS (older Macs, not sure about latest), Windows can't do EXT natively... You can put those VM files on a network share but there goes the performance...

If hardware is not an issue, you can probably use two computers. One to be your everyday computer with 3 operating systems installed, and another bare metal hypervisor running say ESXi for all your virtualizaton needs. This way you can access any VM via remote desktop.

Answer (score 0):

If the hardware is Apple, then run OSX natively (no dual-boot), and run Linux & Windows in  VM's (e.g., VirtualBox). Note that you'll need a Windows license -- decide if you'll be using Windows enough to really warrant it.

If it's generic PC hardware, dual boot with both windows & linux, picking your fav linux distro, but don't worry about ever actually booting into windows: it's too inconvenient switching back & forth.  But do keep windows there, in case you need hardware/vendor-specific firmware updates that can't be installed via Linux.  Boot into linux all the time, and run your Windows & OSX via VM's (e.g., VirtualBox), and also run as many Linux VM's as you want -- but preferring docker over VM's in order to keep the disk & resource usage limited. Again, you'll need licenses for OSX & Windows -- decide if it's really worth the cost before making the investment (it's a long-term, recurring investment). If you are dual-booting to Windows/Linux, you should have license to run a Windows VM while running Linux on the HW (but IANAL).

If you have access to Windows & OSX via another entity (e.g., work or school), I would (imho) just use those environments & let someone else handle the admin & licensing; I do all dev work on Linux, and just test on Windows/OSX (and other Un*x) as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Virtualizing Windows and Linux is relatively easy. Not Mac OS X no matter what anyone tells you.

So your best bet is to use Mac OS X has the host machine software. And then within Mac OS X install virtualization software such as VirtualBox. I do this & it works great!

The big things to keep in mind: RAM and CPU requirements.

Depending on your model of Mac, the CPU can be underpowered to run all three OSes competently. So be sure you have a solid enough CPU to handle virtualization; the more cores the better. And as far as RAM goes, max that out. I have 8GB on a Mac Mini and can run multiple OSes with ease.  Ramp that up to 16GB and guess what? It will be even better.